# SQL to show one result calculated by the other values?

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

It seems we can use a `SQL` statement as:

```
select
  (
    select
      count(*) as c_foos
    from
      foos
  ),
  (
    select
      count(*) as c_bars
    from
      bars
  );
```

but we can't do

```
select
  (
    select
      count(*) as c_foos
    from
      foos
  ),
  (
    select
      count(*) as c_bars
    from
      bars
  ),
  (
    select
      (c_foos / c_bars) as the_ratio
  );
```

or

```
select
  (
    select
      count(*) as c_foos
    from
      foos
  ),
  (
    select
      count(*) as c_bars
    from
      bars
  ),
  (c_foos / c_bars) as the_ratio;
```

Is there a way to do that showing all 3 numbers?  Is there a more definite rule as to what can be done and what can't?

Comment: Please add your DBMS

Comment: you mean mysql or postgres?  Isn't it... the same between them?

Comment: Yes, MySql, Postgres and so on... The statement can be different

Comment: added. I appreciate SQL being declarative, but sometimes it seems there is no definite rule and everything has to be done in one query. Can't there be a definite way to do multiple things and be taken as "1 query"?

Comment: you can't use a subquery in select field list as a variable

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

You define two CTEs in a `WITH` clause, so you can use your result in the main query built on two cte tables (`cte_num` and `cte_den`)

```
WITH recursive
    cte_num AS (
    SELECT count(*) as c_foos
    FROM foos
),
cte_den AS (
    SELECT count(*) as c_bars
    FROM bars
)
SELECT
    cte_num.foos,
    cte_den.bars,
    cte_num.foos / cte_den.bars as the_ratio
from cte_num, cte_den;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a small number of simple rules... but SQL seems so easy that most programmers prefer to cut to the chase, and later complain they didn't get the plot :)

You can think of a query as a description of a flow: columns in a `select` share inputs (defined in `from`), but are evaluated "in parallel", without seeing each other. Your complex example boils down to the fact, that you **cannot** do this:

```
select 1 as a, 2 as b, a + b;
```

fields `a` and `b` are defined as outputs from the query, but there are no inputs called `a` and `b`. All you have to do is modify the query so that a and b are inputs:

```
select a + b from (select 1 as a, 2 as b) as inputs
```

And this will work (this is, btw., the solution for your queries).

Addendum:

1. The confusion comes from the fact, that in most SQL 101 cases outputs are created directly from inputs (data just passes through).
2. This flow model is useful, because it makes things easier to reason about in more complex cases. Also, we avoid ambiguities and loops. You can think about it in the context of query like: `select name as last_name, last_name as name, name || ' ' || last_name from person;`

Answer (score 0):

Move the conditions to the `FROM` clause:

```
select f.c_foos, b.c_bars, f.c_foos / f.c_bars
from (select count(*) as c_foos from foos
     ) f cross join
     (select count(*) as c_bars from bars
     ) b;
```

Ironically, your first version will work in MySQL (see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f13d1d02ba6d8f43ab3c4ab0fce368b4)).  I don't actually think this is intentional. I think it is an artifact of their parser -- meaning that it happens to work but might stop working in future versions.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use a [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) that returns the 2 columns:

```
with cte as (
  select
    (select count(*) from foos) as c_foos,
    (select count(*) from bars) as c_bars
)
select c_foos, c_bars, (c_foos / c_bars) as the_ratio
from cte
```

Note that the aliases of the 2 columns must be set outside of each query and not inside (the parentheses).